# How to make seek bar for AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, sdk, seekbar, avplayer

Im making a iPhone app and want to make a seek bar for a AVPlayer.  I want to make it with a UISlider. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map the duration of the file being played by the AVPlayer to the UISlider's range (maximum and minimum values) using the `duration` property of AVPlayer and make changes in the slider position to set the `currentTime` of the AVPlayer.

Comment: How would I let them change the time

Comment: "... changes in the slider position set the `currentTime` of the AVPlayer." — just quoting myself.

Comment: Ahh sorry thought you meant get the current time from currentTime

Comment: No worries. By the way, your question seems to be an almost exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2654849/635451, which might help you further.

Comment: I am doing the same thing with MPMOvie player controller. But how to change the slider according to seekBar of Movie player. Is there any notification that fires when value of that seekBar chage ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the current duration of the song by slider value

```
- (IBAction)currentTimeSliderTouchUpInside:(id)sender    
 {     
        [self.player stop];    
        self.player.currentTime = self.currentTimeSlider.value;    
        [self.player prepareToPlay];   
        [self play:self];   
 }
```