# How to make the Progressbar(UISlider) work dynamically in my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UISlider to control AVAudioPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654849/uislider-to-control-avaudioplayer)

I'm trying to develop a simple audio player app for iPhone,i need to implement the progress bar which has to run according to song(mediafile) length.How can i accomplish this?can i use slider with timer?
Any help is appreciated in advance, Thank You.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you're playing your audio with `AVPlayer` then you can use its `**addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval**:` method to update your UISlider.  For example, if the name of your slider is `playerScrubber`:

```
    AVPlayerItem *newPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:<your asset>];
    AVPlayer* player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:newPlayerItem];

    CMTime interval = CMTimeMake(33, 1000);  // 30fps
    id playbackObserver = [player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:interval queue:dispatch_get_current_queue() usingBlock: ^(CMTime time) {
            CMTime endTime = CMTimeConvertScale (player.currentItem.asset.duration, player.currentTime.timescale, kCMTimeRoundingMethod_RoundHalfAwayFromZero);
            if (CMTimeCompare(endTime, kCMTimeZero) != 0) {
                    double normalizedTime = (double) player.currentTime.value / (double) endTime.value;
                    playerScrubber.value = normalizedTime;
            }
        }];
```

And later when you're done:

```
[player removeTimeObserver:playbackObserver];
```

Goodluck!

Comment: Works but answer is outdated please update as "dispatch_get_current_queue()" is deprecated since iOS 6

Answer (score 0):

I'd say yes, a UISlider is your best friend. That's what iPod uses, too. You'll have to modify t a bit to indicate the progress visually.
Make a timer that polls the position of your playback and updates the slider's value accordingly.
You might make the slider's minimum value 0 and the maximum value the time of the playback in seconds.

Have a look at this post here on Stack Overflow, it has a pretty good demonstration: [UISlider with ProgressView combined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495433/uislider-with-progressview-combined)

Answer (score 0):

If you use AVAudioPlayer then it has a property called currentTime. You can assign its value to the UIProgressBar value like:

```
progressBar.value=myPlayer.currentTime;
```

You'll need to set up a timer to constantly update the progress.

Comment: `currentTime` works for `AVAudioPlayer`, but not for `AVPlayer`.

Comment: That's why I said `If you use AVAUdioPLayer`. I can't see anywhere me stating that currentTime is applicable for both cases.

Comment: Right @Mike. I see I've commented on this last year when I was stuck with `AVPlayer` myself. However it's not me who has down-voted you on this recently. Həmdə həmvətənıq eləbir!

Comment: Actually I think my comment was because you have `myPlayer` rather than `myAudioPlayer` which can be misleading due to naming convensions.

Comment: Hmmm, the way I code is you either have AVPlayer or AVAudioPlayer. Hardly anyone will use both one for sound output which would cause the misleading you talk about.  Don't you find it awkward?

Comment: I think I was shifting back and forth from `AVPlayer` to `AVAudioPlayer` at that point, because each of them had their own advantages and disadvantages. But my comment has only pointed out that it works with `AVAudioPlayer`, so that in case someone is using `AVPlayer` they wouldn't get confused about it. (: