# Multiple AVPlayers on Separate UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, avfoundation, avplayer

I have multiple `AVPlayers`, each on separate `UIViewControllers` playing different songs.
I need to pause one `AVPlayer` whenever I play another one (*otherwise the audio overlaps*).
 I would like to let the user traverse through the app while the music plays in the background, so pausing the `AVPlayer` on `viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated`, would not work.
 What is the best way to access the controls of each separate `AVPlayer`?

Comment: It's not exactly what you want or need, but check this example, it might give some guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877110/objective-c-need-help-creating-an-avaudioplayer-singleton/9880450#9880450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion a singleton with only 1 AVPlayer solves this issue well. This way you guarantee that to play another song you have to stop the previous. Then, in that AVPLayerSingleton you have a private property called avPlayer. You can define two methods:

```
- (void)createPlayerWithSong:(NSString *)currentSong;
- (void)destroyPlayer
```

Then, in your createPlayerWithSong you can check if avPlayer is already created and destroy it and create a new one for each new song.

Comment: Wouldn't destroying the AVPlayer stop me from continuing the song where I left off? I want to pause it, not kill it.

Comment: Yes, it would. You can save the time where you stopped or have more AVPlayers. However I still believe that a singleton is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways you *could* do it:

Create a shared singleton object that have weak properties that reference each AVPlayer. That way you can control it from anywhere.

OR

Use NSNotificationCenter to send notifications when you want to control an AVPlayer on a different view controller. This might get cumbersome if you have a lot of AVPlayers you want to control.