# AVAudioPlayer getting wrong file duration iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, avaudioplayer

I am using AVAudioPlayer object to load audio file.
I have checked with two browser 1) chrome is getting exact duration. while 2) Safari is getting wrong file duration.

We have used the code as per below,

```
let soundData =  NSData(contentsOf: url as URL)
self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(data: soundData! as Data)                   
self.player.delegate = self
let currentSecond = self.player.duration

//Second Option we had tried.
 let assets = AVURLAsset(url: url as URL, options: [
 AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey : Int(true)])
 var t = Float()
 t = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(assets.duration))
 print(t)
```

[image]

Is there any suggestion?
OR am I missing something?
please guide me.

Comment: Did you find any solution to it. I am also facing same problem in iOS 10 and mac Sierra, while its working fine in iOS 11 and mac high sierra. Is this some bug which is resolved by apple team in newer updates.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `player.prepareToPlay()` before you can get duration.

Comment: this is a strange bug but calling it fixes the case...