# NSString formatting

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, stringwithformat

I'm changing some pre-written code and a video timeLabel is formatted like so:

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d:%0.2d", minutes, seconds];
```

What's happening is the if the `minutes` is a single digit, it's returning a space before it, eg `4:49` has a space before the 4. How do I format so that there are 2 characters in the string if the `minutes` arguments is 2 digits, but just 1 character if `minutes` is 1 digit?

Comment: your final output should be m:ss ?

Comment: Say `man printf` in the Terminal. Read.

Comment: Read the specifications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the following:

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", minutes, seconds];
```

Simply using `%d` will show the number in however many digits it needs. And the `seconds` shouldn't have a decimal. The `%02d` says to show with at least two digits and left fill with leading zeros to ensure there are two digits if needed.

Comment: Actually the number before the decimal is for padding with space vs number after the decimal is for padding with zeros. For example with var myInt = Int(13), NSString(format: "%3d", myInt) = " 13" (one leading space), NSString(format: "%.3d", myInt) = "013", NSString(format: "%3.3d", myInt) = "013" and NSString(format: "%5.3d", myInt) = "  013" (two leading spaces)

Comment: @rockhammer What I posted works just fine. What you posted is normally used with floating pointing numbers and the `%f` specifier.

Comment: Understood. It's just that practically every solution people post about converting NSTimeInterval to human readable format uses something like `return NSString(format: "%0.2d:%0.2d:%0.2d.%0.3d",hours,minutes,seconds,ms)` such as this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/28872601/1827488. And I just discovered this decimal convention for `%d` does not work on Android/java as I port code over there.