# How to give track action in progress bar in ios

Tags: objective-c, progress-bar

In my iPhone app I am playing audio file. I want to forward the audio when we press to progress Bar.Can anybody give me a tutorial link or example code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What player are you using? Does it allow seeking? Does it have a slider property?

Comment: AVAudioPlayer is used for play audio

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654849/uislider-to-control-avaudioplayer ?